# Verify the homogeneous differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$xy''-(1+x)y'+y=x^2e^{2x}$

How to verify that $y_1=e^x$ and $y_2=1+x$ are solution for homogeneous differential equation.

I already plugging $y_1=e^x,y_1'=e^x,y_1''=e^x$ and $y_2=1+x,y_2'=1,y_2''=0$ into equation but i get $x^2e^{2x}$ still didn't get $0$.

Comment: is it $e^{2x}$ or $e^2\cdot x$?

Comment: opps, sorry i did some mistake is $e^{2x}$, i already edit

Answer (score 1):

The solution $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the homogeneous differential equation, that means, the right side is $0$. What you are confusing this is with a Particular solution. Refer to this on the solution of non-homogenous DE, http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt2.pdf

Comment: Does it means that the above question is about non-homogeneous DE? And the ways of solving it is different from hoemogeneous DE?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about second-order linear equations. Usually, in textbooks, solving starts from the property 
$y=y_c+y_p$,

where yc is a solution of **homogeneous** equation, and yp is a solution of **nonhomogeneous** equation. So $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not final solutions; they're rather two possible variants of $y_c$.

Now let's look at the problem from this point of view. By definition, if your **nonhomogeneous** de=f(x), then $y_c$ is solution for the situation when **homogeneous** de=0. Simply replace x^2*e^2x with 0.

Then, xy''-(1+x)y'+y=0 has solutions y1 and y2. Let's check.

$$x*e^x-(1+x)*e^x+e^x=0$$

$$x*0-(1+x)*1+(1+x)=0$$
Both are true.